# How to mock an object/method for certain parameters only

Tags: python, pandas, python-unittest.mock

I'm writing a test that asserts that a certain method is called with certain parameters.

I have a method that does some `pandas.Timestamp()` calls and some of them include `pandas.Timestamp("now")`. And this is where the problem arises.

```py
class MyClass(object):
    def my_method(start, stop):
        start = start if pd.isna(start) else pd.Timestamp(0)
        stop = end if pd.isna(end) else pd.Timestamp("now")

        result = self.perform_calc(start, stop)
        return result

    def perform_calc():
        pass
```

When I patch `pd.Timestamp` I also patch it for the 0-case in addition to "now". How can I make a patch where `pd.Timestamp` acts normal for all other cases than `pd.Timestamp("now")`?

I have tried to make a `side effect` function:

```py
def side_effect(t):
    if t == "now":
        return pd.Timestamp("2019-01-01")
    else:
        return pd.Timestamp(t)
```

But it seems that once `pd.Timestamp` is patched, this is also patched, so I get a recursion error.

```py
    @patch("my_module.pd.Timestamp", side_effect=side_effect)
    @patch("my_module.MyClass.perform_calc")
    def test_my_method(self, mock_ts, mock_calc):
        start = pd.Timestamp("NaT")
        stop= pd.Timestamp("NaT")
        my_class = my_module.MyClass()
        my_class.my_method(start, stop)

        mock_calc.assert_called_once_with(
            pd.Timestamp(0), pd.Timestamp("2019-01-01")
        )
```

Basically, I want to fix the return value for `pd.Timestamp("now")` to a fixed date, while everything else is parsed normally.

Edits: Made changes to examples after questions.

Comment: sorry this might be me but i do not understand what you are trying to do:
"When I patch pd.Timestamp I also patch it for the 0-case in addition to "now". How can I make a patch where pd.Timestamp acts normal for all other cases than pd.Timestamp("now")?" what does this mean?

Comment: Can you please show the whole code where you patch `pd.Timestamp` not only `side_effect` function?

Comment: I've made some updates after your comment Bendik Knapstad. I want `pd.Timestamp(0)` to return `1970-01-01`, but I want `pd.Timestamp("now")` not to return actual now, but a fixed time, e.g. `2019-01-01`.